# i want to print result of two number in third text box in same page in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

```
<html>
<body>
 <form action="first.jsp" method ="get">
 first number<input type="text" name="n1"><br>
 Second number<input type="text" name="n2"><br>

 <input type="submit" name="s1">
 </form>
 <%
String n1 = request.getParameter("n1");
String n2 = request.getParameter("n2");
int i1 = Integer.parseInt(n1);
int i2 = Integer.parseInt(n2);
int i3 = i1+i2;
%>

 Result<input type="text" name="n3" value =<%=i3 %>>
</body>
</html>
```

Should I create separate jsp and html page 
if yes then how can I print the value in n3
how can I print addition value in n3

Answer (score 1):

```
 <html>
 <head>
<script>
function addition()
{
var a = parseInt(form.input1.value);
var b = parseInt(form.input2.value);
var c = a+b;
document.getElementById("aa").value = c;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="GET">
First Number
<input type="text" name="input1" value=20><br>
Second Number 

<input type="text" name="input2" value=10><br>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addition()">
Result
<input type="text" id="aa" name="input3" ><br>

</form>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: You should use java script function to disply the result in same page